# Please configure Android SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

**I am getting this error:**

> Please `configure` Android SDK

Onclick of configure i getting one popup

[image]

Comment: can you tell me the  reason for downvote please

Comment: Update your copy of Android `SDK` and Verify the `Android SDK` location @Gowthaman M

Comment: @Dhanshri i set  **Android SDK** location right place checked

Comment: @Dhanshri when i create new project it's working fine....i was working this project past 3mon..today  i getting this error

Comment: @Dhanshri i am using **android studio 2.3** when create new project it's working fine...i want to resolve the issuses

Comment: No down vote here!

Comment: @Brian Reinhold so what

Comment: @GowthamanM just trying to support you in the sense that this was a worth while question and did not deserve the down vote you referred to in an earlier comment.

Comment: @Brian Reinhold oh okkkk....if you want to see downvote here..,you need to earn 1000 reputation to expand votes check this link  https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After changing **Build Tool Version** on the pop screen

```
 26.0.1 changed into 26.0.3   // else selected the highest available version
```

then click OK started working for me...

(or)

Simply Restart **Andoid Studio** `File->Invalidate Caches and restart`

Comment: This worked for me as well, I selected the highest available version from the combo box and then had to restart Android Studio.  Now my device (Pixel2XL was detected by logcat).

Answer (score 15):

**FIX FOR 3.1.2 OR NEWER VERSIONS**

I  faced the same issue on **Android studio 3.1.2**, but a simple Sync didn't work for me.The solution was a bit different:
I go to

1. File -> Invalidate Caches -> Invalidate

[image: first step]

2. File -> Close Project.
3. Remove the project from the Android Studio project selector window.
4. Quit from Android Studio(X)
5. Start Android studio and open project again

[image: second step open project]

Answer (score 9):

I consumed a few hours to fix this issue:

> - First Click **'Sync'** gradle
> - Then `clean` and `rebuild` the application
> - And `invalidate and restart`

Comment: Uhm, I guess it should be from menu `File` -> `Sync Project with Gradle Files`, right?

Comment: @superjos Noooo...it should be `File->Invalidate Caches and restart...`

Answer (score 4):

You can close this project first.
Then **DELETE ALL** temp file and generated file, 
including `.gradle`, `.idea`, `build` in your project's root directory and also `build` in `app` path.
Finally, restart your project, problem should be solved. Good Luck !

Comment: Yes this fixed many problems including this one! Isn't this what Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean should do?

Comment: @Sctajc no, Flutter clean deletes `build` and `build_ios` folders inside you project dir

Comment: It will work for those who copied the project directory instead of cloning it from repository or maybe try to run on a different environment or reinstalled Android Studio

Answer (score 1):

After executing these two adb commands, it also works fine for me.

**(1) adb kill-server**

**(2) adb start-server**

Comment: Worked for me too. Needed AS restart though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried all of the above and it did not help.

I ended up closing everything and rebooting my Mac.

Reopened Android Studio and it was back to normal :)

Answer (score 0):

In `build.gradle (Module: app)` I changed `"compileSdkVersion 23"` to `26`
Then it works.

Maybe also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me solution was to **sync project with gradle files**.

[image]